# How to concatenate two byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, memorystream

i use this method to merge existing pdf documents and add new pdf documents to it (in memory not physical)
the problem i have 2 memory stream one for merged pdf and one to the new document then convert it to byte array, i want to concat these tow arrays

```
public static byte[] merge(List<String> pdf)
{
    MemoryStream copystream;
    MemoryStream ms;
    using (ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Document document;
        using (document = new Document())
        {
            using (PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
            {
                wri.CloseStream = false;
                document.Open();
                document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4); // for vertical layout

                document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello"));

                document.Close();

                copystream = new MemoryStream();
                Document doc = new Document();
                using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, copystream))
                {
                    copy.CloseStream = false;
                    copy.Open();
                    doc.Open();

                    // copy.AddPage(PageSize.A4, 0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf[i]);
                        // loop over the pages in that document
                        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                        for (int page = 0; page < n;)
                        {
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                        }
                    }

                    copy.Close();
                    copystream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    copystream.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] mergedPdf2 = copystream.ToArray();
        byte[] mergedPdf3 = ms.ToArray();
        byte[] result = new byte[mergedPdf2.Length + mergedPdf3.Length];
        mergedPdf2.CopyTo(result, 0);
        mergedPdf3.CopyTo(result, mergedPdf2.Length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `i want to concat these tow arrays` Does your current code work? What do you expect it to do that it doesn't do?

Comment: If you concat those two memory streams, the result won't be a valid PDF. Why don't you simply add the pdf in `ms` to `copy`?

Answer (score 8):

There's a  LINQ method, in `byte[]`, that allows concatenation.

```
a.Concat(b).ToArray();
```

You have to add `using System.Linq;`first. If you don't want to do that you can create a method, somthing like:

```
 static byte[] Concat(byte[] a, byte[] b)
 {           
     byte[] output = new byte[a.Length + b.Length];
     for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
         output[i] = a[i];
     for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
         output[a.Length+j] = b[j];
     return output;           
 }
```